# Update data in multiple tables using outer join - result must post to View AND Table

Tags: sql, replace, sql-update, outer-join

I have selected and joined the following successfully:

```
SELECT     
   WOEQLVW.WONUM, WOEQLVW.EQNUM, WOEVW.EMPCODE, WOEVW.WODATE, WOEVW.ESTHRS,   
   WOEVW.REGHRS, WO.WOTYPE, WO.ATFIRSTNAME, 
   WO.ATLASTNAME, WO.SCHEDSTARTDATE, WO.STATUS, WOEVW.EQNUM AS Expr1, WOEVW.LASTNAME
FROM         
   WOEQLVW 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   WOEVW ON WOEQLVW.WONUM = WOEVW.WONUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   WO ON WOEQLVW.WONUM = WO.WONUM
WHERE 
   (WO.SCHEDSTARTDATE > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-08 00:00:00', 102))  
   AND (WO.WOTYPE = 'SAFE-T') 
   AND (WO.STATUS = 'M')
```

I need to need to first make

```
WOEVW.EMPCODE = WO.ATLASTNAME
then, set WOEVW.ESTHRS and WOEVW.REGHRS = '1.00' 
then, set WOEVW.WODATE = WO.SCHEDSTARTDATE
```

and all of the items in the WHERE clause must be applied BEFORE I make these changes to my tables.

I have tried UPDATE and WHERE EXISTS after the initial query (above) but have had no ability to get the View to show the updates even though I tried:

```
UPDATE WOEVW
SET REGHRS = '1.00'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT WO.WOTYPE
              FROM WO
              WHERE WO.WOTYPE = 'SAFE-T');
```

I got:

(508 row(s) affected)

(564 row(s) affected)

This is troublesome because there are exactly 162 records of this type. When I use the SELECT statement again, I don't see any changes.

Any of the 'tables' that end with VW are Views and not proper tables.  The program that should be displaying the results is Infor/MP2.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? Which version? Does the view show the updates when you use SQL Server Management Studio to view the results?

Comment: Have you committed the transaction? --read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html . In an Oracle DB, you have to commit the transaction, unless you do it through a "concurrent program" which does an implicit commit. Either way, I've had this one bite me a few times :(

Comment: My SQL Server version is:  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (Intel X86)   Sep 22 2011 00:28:06   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) and no, the view does not show the updates when I use SQL Server Management studio to view the results.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work.

```
SELECT WO.WOTYPE
FROM WO
WHERE WO.WOTYPE = 'SAFE-T'
```

will run and find 162 records.  Then the outer query runs:

```
UPDATE WOEVW
SET REGHRS = '1.00'
WHERE EXISTS
```

If any row at all was returned by the first row, the second command will update every row.  All the where is asking is if anything at all is returned, it will return true.  You need to link the subquery with the outer query so for every row in WOEVW it checks WO. You can try something like:

```
UPDATE WOEVW
SET REGHRS = '1.00'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT WO.WOTYPE
              FROM WO
              WHERE WO.WOTYPE = 'SAFE-T' AND WOEVW.WONUM = WO.WONUM );
```

You can also try a join if you like.

```
UPDATE W1
SET REGHRS = '1.00'
FROM WOEVW W1
JOIN WO W2 ON  WOEVW.WONUM = WO.WONUM 
WHERE WO.WOTYPE = 'SAFE-T'
```

I don't know your exact table structure so I can't be sure WOEVW.WONUM = WO.WONUM is the correct join condition.

As to why the update failed, check for triggers on WOEVW to see if they are stopping you.  You could also have forgot to commit.

Comment: Tried to execute the join mentioned above and received a multi-part identifier error.  I then tried to provide an alias which usually solves the problem but in Design Query there is no column provided for Alias with this particular join.